# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at com.squareup.okhttp.Cache.<init>(Cache.java:172)

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, okhttp

I am using "compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'" library to display images by passing urls of the images to it raises error.

ArrayList varible contains url of the multi image.

https://www.android-examples.com/android-multiple-auto-image-slider-example-tutorial-using-online-url/

app.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.tho.oe"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
```

Some of the main lines from class

```
private ArrayList<String> collecter = new ArrayList<>();
sliderLayout = (SliderLayout)findViewById(R.id.slider);

TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(Main2Activity.this);
        for (int i = 0; i<collecter.size();i++ ) {

            textSliderView
                    .description(collecter.get(i))
                    .image(collecter.get(i).toString())
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                    .setOnSliderClickListener(Main2Activity.this);
            textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
            textSliderView.getBundle()
                    .putString("extra", collecter.get(i));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"HI Thofiq"+collecter.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        sliderLayout.addSlider(textSliderView);
        sliderLayout.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion);
        sliderLayout.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
        sliderLayout.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
        sliderLayout.setDuration(3000);
        sliderLayout.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Error:

```
   11-11 21:25:30.045 18458-18458/com.google.tho.oe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                           at com.squareup.okhttp.Cache.<init>(Cache.java:172)
                                                                           at com.squareup.okhttp.Cache.<init>(Cache.java:168)
                                                                           at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:78)
                                                                           at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:55)
                                                                           at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:45)
                                                                           at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$OkHttpLoaderCreator.create(Utils.java:424)
                                                                           at com.squareup.picasso.Utils.createDefaultDownloader(Utils.java:250)
                                                                           at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Builder.build(Picasso.java:832)
                                                                           at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.with(Picasso.java:662)
                                                                           at com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.BaseSliderView.bindEventAndShow(BaseSliderView.java:210)
                                                                           at com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.TextSliderView.getView(TextSliderView.java:25)
                                                                           at com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderAdapter.instantiateItem(SliderAdapter.java:81)
                                                                           at com.daimajia.slider.library.Tricks.InfinitePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(InfinitePagerAdapter.java:54)
                                                                           at com.daimajia.slider.library.Tricks.ViewPagerEx.addNewItem(ViewPagerEx.java:848)
                                                                           at com.daimajia.slider.library.Tricks.ViewPagerEx.populate(ViewPagerEx.java:998)
                                                                           at com.daimajia.slider.library.Tricks.ViewPagerEx.populate(ViewPagerEx.java:930)
                                                                           at com.daimajia.slider.library.Tricks.ViewPagerEx.onMeasure(ViewPagerEx.java:1453)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2011)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1250)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1425)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1143)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4674)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                        at android.os
```

Comment: That does not look like the COMPLETE stack trace. There should be one or more "caused by" sections, which are critical to understanding the actual issue.

Comment: read https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2228

Comment: Doesn't seems to be the same issue based on the exception. But we need the full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'` this dependency. This can cause errors if your image loader library uses a different version of okhttp. You have to add next dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
```

}

and use versions of libraries like in the example, because incompatibility with new versions is possible.
And see if you have not forgotten to add permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
```

Also an error can happen if you have 2 or more `okhttp` instances. so check it.
and as written by IntelliJ Amiya, you can see this issue on the githab https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2228 
Perhaps the solution given there will help you, but it is for `okhttp` so you should change the code in the daimajia.slider lib.